# c# Copy growing memorystream to a new memorystream

Tags: readonly, memorystream, c#-5.0

I have a MemoryStream that is being filled by a call, each 16000 bits.

I need to create a copy without moving the position, because if I move it, the call write the next bits in the wrong place.

¿Is there any way i can copy a MemoryStream to a new MemoryStream with readonly, without moving the position?

Comment: [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) ?

Comment: is necesary to set position to 0, in order to use CopyTo... and that makes the flow writes where the position is while reading.

Comment: `ToArray()` will help you.

Comment: @Fraga then why not reset the position to original after you copy it?

Comment: Cause another process is always adding new bits (from the call) and if i move the position, the process add the bits wherever is the position. I tryied with ToArray(), and it works, but that like making a copy with translate in bytes... is there any way faster to create a new MemoryStream?

Comment: You can always write your own proxy streams to do [something like this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12823/XML-forking-in-NET-Framework).